# Playwright test is failing occasionally when I'm trying to test whether the textbox is on focus

Tags: c#, xunit, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I have the following test:

```cs
namespace RazorSharp.Pages;

using Microsoft.Playwright;

using Xunit;

public class TextBoxPageTests : IClassFixture<TestServerHostFixture>
{
    private readonly string _serverAddress;

    public TextBoxPageTests(TestServerHostFixture testServerHost)
        => _serverAddress = testServerHost.ServerAddress;

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_set_focus()
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            
        await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true
        });
            
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
            
        var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
            
        await page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () => await page.GotoAsync($"{_serverAddress}/textbox"),
                                              response => response.Ok);

        var button = page.GetByTestId("set-focus");

        await button.WaitForAsync();

        var textbox = page.GetByTestId("textbox");
            
        await textbox.WaitForAsync();

        await button.ClickAsync();
                
        await Assertions.Expect(textbox).ToBeFocusedAsync();
            
        await browser.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

But for some reason it occasionally fails with the following error:

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: Locator expected to be focused

Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException
Locator expected to be focused 
Call log:
LocatorAssertions.ToBeFocusedAsync with timeout 5000ms
waiting for GetByTestId("textbox")
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
waiting for GetByTestId("textbox")
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
  locator resolved to <input type="text" minlength="-1" maxlength="-1" data-t…/>
  unexpected value "not focused"
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.AssertionsBase.ExpectImplAsync(String expression, FrameExpectOptions expectOptions, Object expected, String message) in /_/src/Playwright/Core/AssertionsBase.cs:line 87
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.AssertionsBase.ExpectImplAsync(String expression, ExpectedTextValue[] expectedText, Object expected, String message, FrameExpectOptions options) in /_/src/Playwright/Core/AssertionsBase.cs:line 63
   at RazorSharp.Pages.TextBoxPageTests.Should_set_focus() in /Users/eyal/Development/Projects/RazorSharp/src/RazorSharp.Tests.E2E/Pages/TextBox.page.tests.cs:line 41
   at RazorSharp.Pages.TextBoxPageTests.Should_set_focus() in /Users/eyal/Development/Projects/RazorSharp/src/RazorSharp.Tests.E2E/Pages/TextBox.page.tests.cs:line 43
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.AggregateAsync(Func`1 asyncAction) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/ExecutionTimer.cs:line 48
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.RunAsync(Func`1 code) in /_/src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs:line 90
```

The things I've tried are as followed:

1. Call `RunAndWaitForResponseAsync` and only then call `GotoAsync` and finally check the response status like this:

```cs
await page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () => await page.GotoAsync($"{_serverAddress}/textbox"),
    response => response.Ok);
```

2. Call `WaitForAsync` below `GetByTestId` calls like this:

```cs
var button = page.GetByTestId("set-focus");

await button.WaitForAsync();

var textbox = page.GetByTestId("textbox");

await textbox.WaitForAsync();
```

I'm new to Playwright so I might be doing something completely wrong but I can't figure what exactly and where but my manual tests and unit tests are all passing so I know the components participating and existing in the page work correctly.